# Adding CSS Class to Dropdown or Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I tried to add a CSS Class to the Dropdown, but it is resulting in a Console Error.

> Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/dropdownCss

```
$('.myfilter').select2({
            placeholder: name,
            allowClear: true,
            dropdownCssClass: "mytestdropdown",
});
```

What I try to achieve is to add a Class to the Dropdown, so I can style the Dropdown-Elements of one Dropdown with CSS (Instead of just styling all Select2 Dropdowns all over the Website!)

Answer (score 0):

select2 is depended on the version of select2 that you are using. The HTML structure changed in one of the versions.

```
   $(".jSelectbox").select2();
```

And put 'error' class on the select box.

```
 .error + .select2-container, 
.error + .select2-container + .select2-container .select2-dropdown {
    border: 3px solid red !important;
}
```

```js
$(".jSelectbox").select2();
```

```css
.error + .select2-container, 
.error + .select2-container + .select2-container .select2-dropdown {
    border: 3px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="jSelectbox error">
   <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
   <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
   <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
   <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
   <option value="CA">California</option>
   <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
   <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
   <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
   <option value="FL">Florida</option>
   <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
   <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>                   
   <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
   <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
   <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
   <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
   <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
   <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
   <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
   <option value="ME">Maine</option>
   <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
   <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
   <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
   <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
   <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
   <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
   <option value="MT">Montana</option>
   <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
   <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
   <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
   <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
   <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
   <option value="NY">New York</option>
   <option value="NC" selected="">North Carolina</option>
   <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
   <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
   <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
   <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
   <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
   <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
   <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
   <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
   <option value="TX">Texas</option>
   <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
   <option value="UT">Utah</option>
   <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
   <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
   <option value="WA">Washington</option>
   <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
   <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
   <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: A good answer contains a better explanation than "Try this". It should at least explain what you've done and why.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there are 2 select2 files:

select2.js
ans select2.full.js

For my purpose one would need the select2.full.js - otherwise the options dropdownCssClass and containerCssClass are not working.